# Conditional root_url (index)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like my application to display different data on the frontpage depending on whether the user has been logged in or not.

```
def index

  if current_user
    # render another controllers action
  else
    # render another controllers action
  end

end
```

I can achieve this by using render_component. However it has been obsolete for some time. Although I can still use it as a plugin, I'm interested if anyone has a better approach.
Just take in mind that rendering another controller's view directly is not an option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use your `index` method as a public proxy to the specific view you want to render.

```
def index
  if user?
    logged_in
  else
    logged_out
  end
end

private

def logged_in
  # stuff
  render :action => "logged_in"
end

def logged_out
  # stuff
  render :action => "logged_out"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a relatively small subsection of data, I'd probably do that in a view helper.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't apply very well for my application.

Comment: It might be useful to explain more of what your exact situation is: it seems like you're looking for something in between doing a redirect_to different actions and a view helper.